# Unresponsive page due to select2 selector

Tags: html, jquery-select2

I have 200k entries to insert into select2 field, my web page become unresponsive. I don't feel like divide them into 500 entries per file, then insert 500 by 500. Is there any shortcut/way to insert all my data into it? Would appreciate your help :)

Comment: So you insert 200 000 rows in a table, which freeze your web page, and you ask for a way to insert all those rows without loosing control of your page ?

Comment: yes, it ask me to exit the page or wait the page to be responsive

Comment: That's a subject a bit too broad to be covered in a single answer, but take a look at [asynchronous requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) and maybe that [article](https://www.theserverside.com/news/1363576/What-is-the-Asynchronous-Web-and-How-is-it-Revolutionary). Basically, try finding tutorials, guides and all about Ajax, asynchronous queries